# Casting a Super Class in to a Sub Class

Tags: c#, casting, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I have a class that looks like:

```
public class MySuperClass
{
  public void PrintValue()
  {
    print("SUPER Class");
  }
}
```

I then have another class that looks like:

```
public class MySubClass : MySuperClass
{
  public void PrintSubValue()
  {
    print("SUB Class");
  }
}
```

Then, I have a situation where I have a third class that looks like:

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
  public MyOtherClass(MySuperClass someSubClass)
  {
    someSubClass.PrintSubValue();
  }
}
```

It won't compile... As is to be expected.

Now if I change `MyOtherClass` to look like:

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
  public MyOtherClass(MySuperClass someSubClass)
  {
    someSubClass = (MySubClass) someSubClass;
    someSubClass.PrintSubValue();
  }
}
```

It still won't compile... This I didn't expect.

Why am I unable to cast a Super Class to a Sub Class? And how can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why am I unable to cast

You are able to cast, but then you assign it back to `MySuperClass someSubClass` which implicitly casts it back to `MySuperClass`.

Use

```
var castedSomeSubClass = (MySubClass)someSubClass;
```

or

```
MySubClass castedSomeSubClass = (MySubClass)someSubClass;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes a lot of sense. :)